# PyCharm does not find cv2 no matter what I try

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I tried to install OpenCV in so many ways. I tried this tutorial:

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/db2/tutorial_macos_install.html

I tried using conda:

conda install -c conda-forge opencv

etc. etc.

But when I type in import cv2 it says:

[PyCharm Image OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbY1R.png)

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: just try to run it once.

Answer (score 0):

To install opencv you can either build it with CMake (like the link you tagged) or install a pre-built version of it (easier).

You can do the pre-built via PyCharm going to your project settings and adding the 'opencv-python' package or running `pip install opencv-python`

If you need both main and contrib modules you can install 'opencv-contrib-python' instead

Here's the package's page: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Let's say I try It again with CMake. My first question would be, do I build it in my working directory or somewhere else? Second, how would the find_package command in step 6 look exactly? It did not really work when I tried it...